How to plot multiple data sets from excel file in one plot in matplotlib?
I would like to learn how to plot multiple data sets taken from excel in one plot. The code below (provided kindly by another user) plots data sets in separate plots. It works great. Now I need to combine data for other purposes to show in one plot.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl as xl
df = pd.read_excel("C:\\temp\\test.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet2", skiprows=5)
print(df.columns)
def grouped(iterable, n):
    return zip(*[iter(iterable)]*n)
pair_count = len(list(grouped(df.columns,2)))
pair = 1
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
for x_col,y_col in grouped(df.columns,2):
  x=np.array(df[x_col].values)
  y=np.array(df[y_col].values)
  plt.subplot(1,pair_count,pair)
  plt.xlim(0.1,15)
  plt.ylim(300,800)
  plt.plot(x,y)
  plt.title(f"{pair}. th plot")
  plt.xlabel(f"{x_col}")
  plt.ylabel(f"{y_col}")
  pair += 1
plt.show()

It should look like this:

I would really appreciate your help!
Tried adding fig, ax = plt.subplots() but it created 10 separate graphs.

fig, ax = plt.subplots() belongs outside the loop.

Did you mean to use plt.add_subplot in your loop rather than plt.subplot?

Thank you for your replies! @Jared: plt.add_subplot doesnt work. It says 'matplotlib.pyplot has not attribute add_subplot'.

@BigBen: fig, ax=plt.subplot() outside of the loop gives error "cannot unpack non-iterable axes object".

subplots(), not subplot().

@Olgak Sorry, I meant fig.add_subplot. Before the loop, you should save the result of plt.figure to fig (i.e. fig = plt.figure(...)).

Wait, do you want everything in a single plot or a single figure?

I want it in one graph, i.e. many curves together, each with its own x and y values.

This answer below solves correctly your problem. You can do worse than accept it (i.e., cclick the check mark on its left side)

plot method is enough to add a new line:
def col_pairs(columns):
    return [(columns[i], columns[j]) for i, j in zip(range(0, len(columns), 2), range(1, len(columns), 2))]

for col_x, col_y in col_pairs(df.columns):
    plt.plot(df[col_x], df[col_y], label=f"Line {col_x} vs {col_y}", marker='o')

plt.legend()
plt.show()

output:

